# How to convert a column of mixed time and datetime values to just datetime (or just time)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Here are the columns

```
Time            CloseTime
17  09:30:00  2019-04-22 09:32:00
27  09:30:00  2019-05-13 09:32:00
36  09:30:00             15:15:00
37  09:30:00             15:15:00
44  09:30:00  2019-05-24 09:32:00
76  09:30:00  2019-06-07 09:32:00
92  09:30:00  2019-06-17 09:32:00
```

Currently the `dtype` for both columns is `O`.

I want to convert both columns to `time` so I can compare(subtract) them.

I have tried:

```
df['CloseTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CloseTime'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Close, what you need is convert both columns to timedeltas, second with removed dates, so possible procesing later:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']. astype(str))
df['CloseTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['CloseTime'].str.split().str[-1])

#e.g. subtract columns    
df['diff'] = df['CloseTime'].sub(df['Time'])
print (df)
       Time CloseTime     diff
17 09:30:00  09:32:00 00:02:00
27 09:30:00  09:32:00 00:02:00
36 09:30:00  15:15:00 05:45:00
37 09:30:00  15:15:00 05:45:00
44 09:30:00  09:32:00 00:02:00
76 09:30:00  09:32:00 00:02:00
92 09:30:00  09:32:00 00:02:00
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, I got the following error when I try to run the code: Traceback >(most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx", line 182, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.array_to_timedelta64
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx", line 267, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.parse_timedelta_string
TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()

Comment: @Sid Then use `df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']. astype(str))` for convert to strings.

Answer (score 3):

#### `map` + `to_timedelta`

Had a bit of fun with this.

```
x = pd.to_datetime(df['CloseTime']).dt.time.astype(str)
y = df['Time'].astype(str)
# convert `x` and `y` to `timedelta`, then subtract
df['diff'] = pd.Series.sub(*map(pd.to_timedelta, (x, y)))
df

        Time            CloseTime     diff
17  09:30:00  2019-04-22 09:32:00 00:02:00
27  09:30:00  2019-05-13 09:32:00 00:02:00
36  09:30:00             15:15:00 05:45:00
37  09:30:00             15:15:00 05:45:00
44  09:30:00  2019-05-24 09:32:00 00:02:00
76  09:30:00  2019-06-07 09:32:00 00:02:00
92  09:30:00  2019-06-17 09:32:00 00:02:00
```